# Jquery constraint proportions with width and height input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with width and height input fields.
I want to listen to changes made in any one of the fields by the user
and change the value in the other field wile constraint proportions using Jquery.
the user can see the changes as he typs.

```
<form>
  <p>
    <label>Width</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="width" value="16" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Height</label>
    <input type="text" id="height" value="9" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have any code already that isn't working? We aren't really here to code things for you, but to help you with problems.

Answer (score 0):

How about this. I am storing the original value in data-value attribute, that I use to recount the ratio

```
<form>
   <p>
      <label>Width</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="width" data-value="16" value="16" />
  </p>
  <p>
      <label>Height</label>
      <input type="text" id="height" data-value="9" value="9" />
  </p>
</form>​​​​​​​​​
```

Here is the listener for changing width (you can write the one for height in the same way)

```
​$("#width").bind("keyup", function(){
   var width = $(this).data("value")
     , newwidth = $(this).val()
     , $height = $("#height")
     , height = $height.val();

   $height.val(height*(newwidth/width));

})​
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxtwrld/4ayNQ/)

Answer (score 0):

try attaching an event to .keypress( handler(eventObject) ) that for every keypress that the used does it performs what you said above.